# Changing color range 3d plot Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

I am trying to make a 3d plot but the color range is so small that it only covers a small portion of the values that the z-axis can have. How do I fix this?

I attach the code and the image that I get:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(B , ENERGY, result_plot, cmap=cm.Spectral_r , linewidth=0.0 ,antialiased =False)

colorbar( surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=3)


ax.view_init(30, 45)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d plot]

Answer (score 8):

In the future please give a [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The color limits are determined based on your data. Therefore, I'm not entirely certain that your data supports more values than it shows. Using the example from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html), we can use the `vmin` and `vmax` to force limits.

[image]

```
# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, vmin = -10, vmax = 10)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```